# UITableViewController canceling Edit mode animation when calling [table reloadData] inside (void)setEditing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a little problem:

i made my setEditing method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate {   
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animate];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

i'm using the reloadData to call: cellForRowAtIndexPath, and then, if the table is in edit mode, i'll change the appearance of my cell (hiding some labels, for example);

The problem is when i call [mainTableView reloadData] the Edit animation (the red circle slides from left to right and my cell slides to the right) doesn't exist. If don't call it, everything works ok, but i can't customize my cell, since cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called again.

Any suggestion to make it work ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you will try to update your table with **[tableView beginUpdates]** and **[tableView endUpdates]**? Do you need to reload all the cells or only some of them?

**EDIT:** Here's the code for reloading all the cells:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
NSMutableArray *updatedPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSNumber *row in yourArray) {
    NSIndexPath *updatedPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[row intValue] inSection:0];
    [updatedPaths addObject:updatedPath];
}
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:updatedPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

*`yourArray` is NSArray instance where you store your cell.textLabel values or something like that...*

Comment: Actually i just need to update the visible cells, since the cells not shown will call cellForRowAtIndexPath when needed. i tried inserting a reloadData between beginUpdates and endUpdates but it didnt work. Any other sugestion ?? Thank you

Comment: It doesn't work like that. I updated my answer with code example.

Comment: Hey Kashiv, it worked well with your example. Is there anyway to make the animation the Default one for editing the cell ?? the Slide right ?? I tried all types of animation but none of them seem to be the Slide to rigth one.  Thank you

Comment: If you want to have a custom animation, you should look at `CoreAnimation`. PS: If my answer was helpful, upvote and acception would be very appreciated. :)