# Editing controls disappear on reload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Having a bit of trouble.

I've got a UITableView in grouped mode.  The table is set to always be in editing mode - which is working just fine.  All my rows are delete-able.  The rows are indented and all of my UITableViewCellEditControls show up great.

Problem is when a row actually gets deleted I update my data source and then call:

```
deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: //needs to get called because of table aesthetics
```

After the reload occurs (I've tried just a simple reloadData, too) all of my UITableViewCellEditControls (the red circles with the minus signs etc) disappear!  The rows are still indented, but they're gone.

I've tried the suggestion on this post:

[UITableViewController canceling Edit mode animation when calling [table reloadData] inside (void)setEditing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919073/uitableviewcontroller-canceling-edit-mode-animation-when-calling-table-reloadda)

But no luck.

Any help would be REALLY appreciated!

Comment: I am using a custom UITableViewCell and thought that might be part of the problem... but no go.  I just changed things around using the plain old UITableViewCell and the editing controls still disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at any code, I have some suggestions.

According to Apple's [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):  under ReloadData, it says:

> Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the reload. The table view's delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates
>   Blockquote

it shouldn't be called when inserting and deleting rows.

From what it seems like, you are allowing them to delete individual cells, therefore, I am assuming the following methods are already implemented:  `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` In your commitEditingStyle, you should be just calling the delete method with something like this:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This should remove the need for any reload data.  If you don't want to show any animation, you can just use noanimation enumerator instead of the fade I showed in example.

If however, you still think you need to do reload data after every cell deletion, maybe try it with `performSelector:afterDelay:`

Hopefully, this tid-bit helps!

Comment: Hi Bittu, thanks for the info!!  I didn't realize that the reload call shouldn't be made in inserting/deleting rows - answers why the table is acting buggy.  Problem is this:  I am completely customizing the look of my grouped uitableview which includes shadowed top, middle and bottom rows.  Due to the aesthetic requirements, the top and bottom row (specifically because of a drop shadow) need to be a 10px bigger than middle rows.  Now, if the user deletes the TOP row, the 2nd row now becomes the top row - which means it's height and background image needs to update...  is there an easier way?

Comment: You could go couple of ways.  Using KVO, you could monitor the size of the drop shadow on top and bottom and adjust it accordingly.  Also, there might be ways to put some of that drop shadow as part of the section header and footer, so it seems like its attached to the first and last row.  Just throwing some ideas out of there to try.